# Shell script error while executing

Tags: shell

I have written a shell script but it is giving error, following is my code

```
#!/bin/bash
CPU= cat /proc/loadavg | awk '{print$1}'
if  [ $CPU -gt 6 ]
then
echo "Current CPU is: $CPU" | mail -s "CPU Load is Getting High" abc@def.com
fi
```

When I execute this script, it gives the following error:

```
cpu_load.sh: line 3: [: -gt: unary operator expected
```

Comment: That means `$CPU` has non numeric data. Print it before `if` using `echo "<$CPU>"`

Comment: Are you missing a couple of back-ticks in the assignment of `CPU`?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe?

```
CPU=$(cat /proc/loadavg | awk '{print $1}')
```

The `$(...)` called as command substituion - assigning the result of the command to  variable

Answer (score 0):

It means that command `cat /proc/loadavg | awk '{print$1}'` has returned nothing. To workaround it you could assign to variable default value:

```
if  [ ${CPU:-0} -gt 6 ]
```

or you could check variable before use it, like that:

```
if  [ -n "$CPU" -a "$CPU" -gt 6 ]
```